# Appending miniature lists to a larger list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, tuples

I'm creating a python application to play the game Perudo (or Liar's dice).

I am trying to create a function that calculates all the possible moves that the player (or AI) is allowed to make and returns a list of them so that it can reject illegal ones.

Turns are stored as a list of 2 numbers e.g. [10,6] representing ten sixes.
If the starting variable `currentbid` is `[19,3]` (nineteen threes) and there are 20 dice in play, then the only possible moves are 19 fours, 19 fives, 19 sixes, 20 twos, 20 threes, 20 fours, 20 fives and 20 sixes. Calls of ones are not allowed.
The program should output the above as:

```
[[19,4],[19,5],[19,6],[20,2],[20,3],[20,4],[20,5],[20,6]]
```

but instead outputs it as:

```
[[20,6],[20,6],[20,6],[20,6],[20,6],[20,6],[20,6],[20,6]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
def calcpossiblemoves(self, currentbid, totalnoofdice):
    self.possiblemoves = []  # Create a list of possible moves that will be added too

    self.bid = currentbid

    while self.bid[0] <= totalnoofdice:

        while self.bid[1] < 6:
            self.bid[1] += 1
            self.possiblemoves.append(self.bid)     # <- I think the problem is something to do with this line
            print(self.possiblemoves) #For tracking the process

        # Increase 1st number, reset 2nd number to 1

        self.bid[0] += 1
        self.bid[1] = 1 # Which will get increased to 2
        #print("Reached 6")
    return self.possiblemoves
```

Comment: Umm... sounds a bit like Liar's dice or Perudo but without 1's being special...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I had put that in the post, but it appears to have disappeared! Back in now. 1s are special, but I haven't put that in yet :P For now they are just uncallable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `list`s, which are mutable objects, and you're creating references, rather than copies.  You could fix it by copying the `self.bid` list each time, but the most "pythonic" solution is not to use `list`, but to use `tuple`s, instead:

```
def calcpossiblemoves(self, currentbid, totalnoofdice):
    possiblemoves = []

    numberof, value = currentbid

    while numberOf <= totalnoofdice:

        while value < 6:
            value += 1
            possiblemoves.append((numberOf, value))

        # Increase 1st number, reset 2nd number to 1

        numberof += 1
        value = 1 # Which will get increased to 2
        #print("Reached 6")
    return self.possiblemoves
```

Note that this doesn't update `self.bid` (but you can easily add that in), and you get a `list` of immutable `tuple`s.

**EDIT:** Because `tuple`s are immutable, I've used *tuple unpacking* to create two variables.  This is to prevent the following problem:

```
>>> bid = (1, 2)
>>> bid[0] += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I could write `bid = (bid[0]+1, bid[1])`, but using two variables is, imho, easier to understand.

---

Generally, it's a good rule of thumb to make sure that all members of `list`s mean the same thing, whereas values meaning different things go in `tuple`s or `dict`s, or custom containers such as `NamedTuple` or custom classes.

In this example, the outer `list` contains a number of bids, but each of the inner `list`s has a *number of dice* and a *value*, which indicates a `list` is perhaps the wrong type to use.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most helpful answer. Just so that I completely understand it; would it work if I put    'possible moves.append((bid[0],bid[1]))'   ? I assume you have just it for clarity and to emphasise that the two in the tulle are different, following on from your rule of thumb (which is very helpful btw).

Answer (score 1):

You're better off in thinking about a base 6 number here where you effectively have a range of numbers for 20 dice of 0 - 126 inclusive.

```
current_bid = [19, 3]
offset = current_bid[0] * 6 + current_bid[1]
# 117 - and divmod(117, 6) == (19, 3)
```

So, to then get the valid bids that are left, you do the maths over the range of 117 - 126 and get the number of dice and remainder that's valid.

```
valid_bids_with1s = ([n // 6, n % 6 + 1] for n in range(offset, 126))
valid_bids = [[a, b] for a, b in valid_bids_with1s if b != 1]
```

Which gives you:

```
[[19, 4],
 [19, 5],
 [19, 6],
 [20, 2],
 [20, 3],
 [20, 4],
 [20, 5],
 [20, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you're appending the same object in your list which explains you get 6 times the last value.

replace

```
self.possiblemoves.append(self.bid)     # <- I think the problem is something to do with this line
```

by

```
self.possiblemoves.append(list(self.bid)) # make a copy of the list to make it independent from next modifications on self.bid
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reference to self.bid.  It's the same variable over and over again in the list meaning when you update it in your loop, you are updating every instance (all the variables in the list in this case).  I've rewritten what you are trying to do to work the way you want in case you want to keep this same format but as others have said, you can clean it up some from a coding standpoint.

```
def calcpossiblemoves(currentbid, totalnoofdice):
    possiblemoves = []# in range(totalnoofdice)  #Create a list of possible moves that will be added too

    bid = currentbid
    available_bid = None

    while bid[0] <= totalnoofdice:

        while bid[1] < 6:
            bid[1] += 1
            available_bid = [bid[0],bid[1]]
            possiblemoves.append(available_bid)     # <- I think the problem is something to do with this line
            print(possiblemoves) #For tracking the process

        # Increase 1st number, reset 2nd number to 1

        bid[0] += 1
        bid[1] = 1 # Which will get increased to 2
        #print("Reached 6")
    return possiblemoves

calcpossiblemoves([19,3],20)
```

Comment: But why isn't 'available_bid' just a reference to 'bid' ? Is that the difference between 'available_bid = bid' and 'available_bid = [bid[0],bid[1]]' ? What is the difference?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it has to do with the keyword "self".  This documentation explains the "self" keyword pretty well: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/  Basically, the self keyword refers to an instance of a variable within a class or method right?  So if you are running this method and constantly accessing the self.variable, you are access the single instance, not creating new instances of the variable.